# How to add javascript in the head of a HTML knitr document?

Tags: html, r, markdown, knitr

I use the Rmd version of knitr because it is less verbose than Rhtml. I am currently doing

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
```

in the body of the Rmd document, but this should be in the head of the downstream HTML document that gets generated by `markdownToHTML`. Is it possible?

Comment: I think the `<script>` tag can appear after `<body>`. I do not know a good answer to this question except post-processing the html file (e.g. `sub('<body>', '<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>\n<body>', x)`)

Comment: AFAIK, `<script>` tags appearing after `<body>` are valid and should work for d3.js.

Answer (score 4):

You can place the script tags inside your  tags.
then use the tags like this:

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" SRC="jxt1.js"></SCRIPT>
```

you where missing the laguage type there, so the code can understand on which language is he going to "read"

look here (http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jxtern.htm) for more detailed information